# Shared weights for subclass in a siamese model in Tensorflow

Tags: class, networking, tensorflow

I've some problem with the organization of my code in TENSORFLOW.
I want to implement a siamese model that compares the outputs of two convolutional network that have the same weights.

I want to create a class to define my convolutional network, and an other class to define my global model. It seems that there are several ways to share weights (lazy-loading, use many scopes,...) but how can I do this between many objects ?

Are FLAGS useful in my case ?

Any help would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it easiest to use `tf.variable_scope` with `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE`. `tf.name_scope` is optional, but keeps your graphs clean for tensorboard visualizations.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def get_logits(image):
  with tf.variable_scope('my_network', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    # more complex network probably
    x = image
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 3, 1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 3, 1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    x = tf.layers.flatten(x)
    x = tf.layers.dense(x, 10)
    return x


batch_size = 2
height = 6
width = 6

# dummy images
image1 = tf.zeros((batch_size, height, width, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
image2 = tf.zeros((batch_size, height, width, 3), dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.name_scope('instance1'):
  out1 = get_logits(image1)

print(len(tf.global_variables()))  # 6

with tf.name_scope('instance2'):
  out2 = get_logits(image2)

print(len(tf.global_variables()))  # still 6
```

I'm unsure of your exact issue with different objects. If you have multiple different objects, just make sure they call the same function.

```
class MyNetwork(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def get_network_logits(self, image):
    with tf.name_scope(self.name):
      return get_logits(image)

n1 = MyNetwork('instance1')
n2 = MyNetwork('instance2')

l1 = n1(image1)
l2 = n2(image2)
```